# How to redirect stderr of a program that is run using os.system by a third-party python library

Tags: python, io

I use external library, like this:

```
from some_lib import runThatProgram

infile = '/tmp/test'
outfile = '/tmp/testout'
runThatProgram(infile, outfile)
```

while runThatProgram is:

```
def runThatProgram(infile, outfile):
    os.system("%s %s > %s" % ('thatProgram', infile, outfile))
```

The problem is that `'thatProgram'` returns lots of stuff on STDERR, I want to redirect it to a file, **but I cannot edit**  `runThatProgram` **code** because it is in third party lib!

Comment: You should avoid using libraries that do something as breakable and insecure.

Comment: why you aren't you using subprocess ? with subprocess you can set when calling `subprocess.Popen()` the argument `stderr` to the file descriptor that you want to redirect to .

Comment: Rosh, believe me, getting independent on this library is on my TODO list :-)

Comment: mouad, yes, I know subprocess well, it's the external library that uses `os.system`. The `runThatProgram` function was actually implemented quite long time ago, that's why it still uses `os.system`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To illustrate what Rosh Oxymoron said, you can hack the code like this :

```
from some_lib import runThatProgram

infile = '/tmp/test'
outfile = '/tmp/testout 2>&1'
runThatProgram(infile, outfile)
```

with this, it will call

```
thatProgram /tmp/test > /tmp/testout 2>&1
```

that will redirected stderr (2) to stdout (1), and everything will be logged in your outfile.

Comment: This is great! I did with small modification `2>/dev/null` as the runThatProgram needs stdout in the original form, and it worked indeed!

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on using [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html), you can open it, give it a pipe and then work from there so

```
import subprocess
program = "runthatprogram.py".split()
process = subprocess.Popen(program, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = open('stderr','w')) #stderr to fileobj
process.communicate()[0] #display stdout
```